# Is this a Combination or a Permutation?

Tags: statistics, combinatorics

Help Calculate:

A car dealer has 3 body styles, 8 exterior colors and 2 interior color schemes.  How many different cars are there?

Please show work. Thank you.

Comment: There are 11 cars. Nobody says he stocks every _combination_ of body style and color.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right answer?

Comment: Shaily, the answer you're looking for is $48$. See answers below. @Henning is a funny guy :-)

Comment: Thank you. I got confused.

Comment: I guess that we should try to explain to Shaily how to solve these simple permutation questions before the community solve all the exercises to him/her.

Comment: @Sigur: I know how to calculate permutations and combinations. The teacher I have is confusing. I just want to be sure of what I am doing. You are not doing my work for me. I am doing my own. My teacher is not helpful and you guys are helping me with my doubts.

Comment: @Shaily, OK. So you can also post your solution and we can evaluate and help you.

Comment: Will do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is straightforward, by the ["rule of product"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product):

There are $$3 \times 8\times 2 = 48\;$$ different combinations (distinct possible cars) that can be created.

There $3$ choices for body style; $8$ choices for exterior colors, and $2$ choices of interior color schemes:

Since each of these choices are *independent* (the choice of body style doesn't depend on exterior or interior color, e.g.) we multiply the number of choices for each quality to obtain: $\;3 \times 8\times 2 = 48\;$ distinct ways to create a car.

Comment: Your answer was very much helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome: I answered your permutation question.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  If a car type is specified by its body style, exterior color and interior color scheme, then there are 
$$3\cdot8\cdot2=48$$
different car types.